# Not sql files detected when I run flyway info, and when I run flyway migrate files undetected jumping

Tags: flyway

I'm trying flyway.
I have some files with names VX_XX_X__Description.
Not sql files detected when I run flyway info, and when I run flyway migrate files undetected jumping.

Example

V1_1_1__desc1.sql
V1_1_2__desc2.sql
V1_1_3__desc3.sql

When I run only detects some flyway info

V1_1_1__desc1.sql
V1_1_3__desc3.sql

What are the reasons for not detecting the sql files?

Comment: Doublecheck your question. Something doesn't make sense. In the first example the version is correctly separated from the description with two underscores, and in the second one only with a single one.

Comment: You are right!! In the example i didn't use two underscores. But and the end i found the flayway is not case sensitive because it had file names like "*.sql" and "*.SQL"

Comment: I suggest running with debug option (-X on command line) to view the migration flyway finds before executing.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question having the same issue, but with a different cause. Apparently I had the V in the beginning not capitalized. So something like *v201700404__foobar.sql* will not work. It needs to be *V201700404__foobar.sql*

I just wanted to add this to prevent someone else from staring at what's going on like me for some hours.

Answer (score 1):

And the end i found the flayway is not case sensitive because it had file names like ".sql" and ".SQL"

Answer (score 1):

I found this question solving same problem.

In my case I added new sql file only to `src` directory but I forgot to call maven build. (We have flyway configured to seek sql files in `target` directory.)